# Beautiful "waiting view" for iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, cocoa

Is there an open source, reusable, waiting view component for iPad?

I think the UIAcitivityIndicator from iOS is too boring, and I want to present some nice "waiting view" to my users.

Thanks in advance for answering.

RELATED QUESTION: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640805/open-source-ios-components-reusable-views-controllers-buttons-table-cells-e

Comment: IMHO, you should use the platform default style. Then your app will look good together with all other apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another vote here for MBProgressHUD.

Check out Cocoa Controls. It's a website filled with custom, open source iOS controls.

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/

Answer (score 2):

You  may use  the following link to get the attractive Waiting View. I am using it.

https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD